# GPS lat/lons are off by about a mile

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

I have some old data from a flight that was done, it has a series of lat/lons for each datapoint. I've plotted these into Google Earth Pro and I can see that they are plotting about a mile west of where they should be, but not sure whether north/south is off or by how much.

I have the old program and can see that the programmer was taking the lat/lon data from the GPS instrument and dividing everything to the right of the Degrees by 60. Other than that it's a bit of a mystery what is happening.

Is there any obvious information I am missing?

Lat lons look like 44.83125, -78.42333 in the data file, which Google Earth converts to  44°49'52.50"N,  78°25'23.99"W.. I know the longitude should be more like  78°24'23.99"W and I expect that the lat should be more like 44°49'42.50"N or 44°49'32.50"N...lat is much harder to estimate.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed was that after division of everything other than Degrees by 60, the entire thing is formatted to a 5 decimal place float...in case that's somehow relevant.

Comment: Why do you think your points are misplaced? What makes you think that instead of `78°25'23.99"W`, it should be `78°24'23.99"W`? Please edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Instrument response flying over a known anomaly. Im 100% certain the Longitude is off by a mile. The feature being flown over is a N-S linear feature so it's easy to know when we're over it.

Comment: You appear to be treating Degree Minute (Seconds?) data as if it was a decimal which would certainly throw the position off

Comment: @IanTurton I've tried reversing the division by 60 to get Degree Minutes and that doesn't seem to improve anything..If it was originally Degrees Minutes a divison of the Minutes portion by 60 should give decimal degrees, and multiplying the minutes portion by 60 should get back to Minutes. If there were seconds in there I wouldn't know how to extract them since the multiplication by 60 ends up putting 7,8,9's in the seconds slots.  GIS isn't my strong point by any means, so I'm hoping I'm missing something simple :(

Comment: can you add the original code, and some example points and what you think they should be